# Prepend div in other div of several same classes div

Tags: jquery

I have several div called "box". In each "box", i have 3 div and i want to prepend the 2nd div in the first one with jquery (.prepend).

I have that jquery

```
$('.image').prepend($('.header'));
```

```
<div class="box">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="content">           
                <p>text<p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="content">           
                <p>text<p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="content">           
                <p>text<p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

All the "header" go in every "image"
But I would like to have only the corresponding title in its image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code it will works.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.box').each(function(){
  // find the header inside this image
  var $header = $(this).find('.header'); 
  // Prepend to this instance this header
  $(this).find('.image').prepend($header);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="content">           
                <p>text<p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="content">           
                <p>text<p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="content">           
                <p>text<p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**strong text**

Comment: Thanks, I made quite the same : ```$('.box').each(function(){
  // find the header inside the box
  var $header = $(this).find('.header'); 
  // find the image inside the box
  var $image = $(this).find('.image'); 
  // Prepend to this instance this header
  ($image).prepend($header);
});```

Answer (score 1):

This is a time when you can't use a blanket `$(el).append()`, as you've found, every element will be appended.

We use `each` for situations like this, which looks like this:

```
$('.box').each(function(){
  // Code here
});
```

Now `$(this)` refers to the particular `.box` in question.

```
$('.box').each(function(){
  // find the header inside this image
  var $header = $(this).find('.header'); 
  var $image = $(this).find('.image'); 
  // Prepend to this instance this header
  $image.prepend($header);
});
```

I'm a huge fan of `each` and `find` and strongly suggest taking a look at both of them in the docs:

https://api.jquery.com/find/ 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Thanks @Djave, that doesn't work : https://jsfiddle.net/abujelo/efrjz4ms/2/

Comment: I made some changes and it works :) https://jsfiddle.net/abujelo/efrjz4ms/5/ ```$('.box').each(function(){
  // find the header inside the box
  var $header = $(this).find('.header'); 
  // find the image inside the box
  var $image = $(this).find('.image'); 
  // Prepend to this instance this header
  ($image).prepend($header);
});```

Comment: Anyway, you help me a lot ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use each to loop through all image. Hope this helps

```js
$('.image').each(function(e){

$(this).prepend($(this).next());

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="content">           
                <p>text<p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="content">           
                <p>text<p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="content">           
                <p>text<p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```